# Send a Mail with htlm and plain text

Tags: email

I would like, when I write a mail from the contact view (so not CiviMail) and enter my message in the html field and send it, that it also sends out a plain text view. In the current setting, users who use the text-only view receive an empty mail.

And I wouldn't like to have to explain to everyone that they have to copy the written mail into the text-only window again. Is there a technical solution?

Thank you!

[image: Systemstatus]
[image: nur text]
[image: html]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's supposed to automatically fill in the text version based on the html version if the text version is blank.

Some things to check:

- Is the text version in your email completely blank? Does it contain invisible spaces or tabs or blank lines? That will get interpreted as "not empty" so will send what appears to be a blank text version.
- What version of civi are you using? If it's very old it might not do it automatically.

Comment: The mail contains the signature but nothing else of the entered text.

Comment: Ahh interesting. The signature is probably what's making it think it's not blank. I think we could consider that a bug, or at least in need of core improvement.

Comment: hank you very much. Is there anything else I can do about this? Please give me a little hint as to how this works in such a case.

Comment: You can remove the text signature from the user's (sender's) contact record. It's hidden a little bit. It's under the email address when editing the contact record.

Comment: Yes thanks, it worked!